# Applying Whittaker's and Watson's Lagrange theorem to $\sin$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, inequality

I want to use the Lagrange inversion theorem from *Whittaker and Watson*, p. 133, to find the power series of $\sin^{-1}$ at the origin. It should be a valid procedure because $\sin^{-1}$ is analytic at the origin. The theorem is stated as follows:

> Let $f(z)$ and $\phi (z)$ be functions of $z$ analytic on and inside a contour $C$ surrounding a point $a$, and let $t$ be such that the inequality
> $$|t\phi (z)|\lt |z-a|$$
> is satisfied at all points $z$ on the perimeter of $C$; then the equation
> $$\zeta=a+t\phi (\zeta),$$
> regarded as an equation in $\zeta$, has one root in the interior of $C$; and further any function of $\zeta$ analytic on and inside $C$ can be expanded as a power series in $t$ by the formula
> $$f(\zeta)=f(a)+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{t^n}{n!}\dfrac{d^{n-1}}{da^{n-1}}[f'(a)\{\phi (a)\}^n].$$

First, I transform that theorem to a more tractable form for my problem. We can obviously take $f=\operatorname{id}$. Let
$$\phi (z)=\dfrac{z-a}{g(z)-g(a)}.$$
Then
$$\zeta =a+t\dfrac{\zeta-a}{g(\zeta)-g(a)}$$
which gives
$$t=g(\zeta)-g(a).$$
So far, we have
$$\zeta=a+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(g(\zeta)-g(a))^n}{n!}\displaystyle\lim_{z\to a}\dfrac{d^{n-1}}{da^{n-1}} \left(\dfrac{z-a}{g(z)-g(a)}\right)^n.$$
Then let $\zeta=g^{-1}(z)$, so finally
$$g^{-1}(z)=a+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(z-g(a))^n}{n!}\displaystyle\lim_{z\to a}\dfrac{d^{n-1}}{da^{n-1}} \left(\dfrac{z-a}{g(z)-g(a)}\right)^n.$$

We have to find $z$ such that
$$|t \phi(z)|\lt |z-a|$$
for all $z$ on the perimeter of $C$; i.e.
$$\left|(g(\zeta)-g(a))\dfrac{z-a}{g(z)-g(a)}\right|\lt |z-a|,$$
i.e.
$$|g(\zeta)-g(a)|\lt |g(z)-g(a)|$$
which, after using $\zeta=g^{-1}(z)$ and $a=0$ and $\sin 0=0$ simplifies to
$$|z|\lt |g(z)|$$
but **there exists no contour $C$ surrounding the origin such that for all points $z$ on its perimeter we have $|z|\lt |\sin z|$**.

What should I do?

Comment: What is $g$ ? since you are interested  in $\phi(y)=\frac{y}{\sin y}$ and the Taylor expansion of $x\mapsto arc sin x$ in a neighborhood of $0$ it is reasonable to simplify your question by taking $a=0.$ Finally, if it is not for mastering Lagrange but only for getting the Taylor expansion, better is to use the derivative of $arc sin$ which is simple.

Comment: @LetacGérard I'm looking for mastering Lagrange, but you did answer my question in your comment. If you turn it into an answer, I'll give you the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you are looking for a contour $C$ around $0$ such that $M=\min_{z\in C}|\sin z|>0.$ Since if $z=a+ib$ we have
$$2|\sin z|^2=2\sin z \sin \overline{z}=\cos (z-\overline {z})-\cos (z+\overline {z})$$$$ =\cosh 2b-\cos 2a,$$ I suggest the square $C$ with corners $\pm 2a\pm 2ib$ where we have
$$2M^2=\min (1-\cos 2a, \cosh 2b-1)$$ which is strictly positive if $a$ is small enough and $b>0.$